# How to find the support vectors for SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, liblinear

I'm using the liblinear library to train a linear SVM on my data. I have access to the weights for each class of the trained model. But I need to figure out which training instances are acting as support vectors.

The liblinear library doesn't seem to provide these vectors as a model attribute. And I can't seem to figure out how I can find them manually. If I have the training data and I have the weights that define the hyperplane, how would I go about finding these support vectors?

Answer (score 1):

**You can get the support vectors using `clf.support_vectors_`.**

Plotting the support vectors:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm

# we create 40 separable points
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.r_[np.random.randn(20, 2) - [2, 2], np.random.randn(20, 2) + [2, 2]]
Y = [0] * 20 + [1] * 20

# fit the model
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
clf.fit(X, Y)

# get the separating hyperplane
w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (clf.intercept_[0]) / w[1]


margin = 1 / np.sqrt(np.sum(clf.coef_ ** 2))
yy_down = yy - np.sqrt(1 + a ** 2) * margin
yy_up = yy + np.sqrt(1 + a ** 2) * margin

plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.clf()
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
plt.plot(xx, yy_down, 'k--')
plt.plot(xx, yy_up, 'k--')

plt.scatter(clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1], s=80,
            facecolors='none', zorder=10, edgecolors='k')
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, zorder=10, cmap=plt.cm.Paired,
            edgecolors='k')

plt.axis('tight')
x_min = -4.8
x_max = 4.2
y_min = -6
y_max = 6

XX, YY = np.mgrid[x_min:x_max:200j, y_min:y_max:200j]
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[XX.ravel(), YY.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(XX.shape)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.pcolormesh(XX, YY, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking to verify that in a not so linearly separable case, does `support_vectors_` return support vectors with positive slack as well?

Comment: what do you mean "positive slack"? If you have fitted a linear SVM model, the code is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume we are talking about [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/) instead of [sklearn svc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html).

The answer can be found in the [LIBLINEAR FAQ](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/liblinear/FAQ.html). In short, you can't. You need to modify the source code.

> **Q: How could I know which training instances are support vectors?**
>
> Some LIBLINEAR solvers consider the primal problem, so support
> vectors are not obtained during the training procedure. For dual
> solvers, we output only the primal weight vector w, so support vectors
> are not stored in the model. This is different from LIBSVM.
>
> To know support vectors, you can modify the following loop in
> solve_l2r_l1l2_svc() of linear.cpp to print out indices:

```
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        v += alpha[i]*(alpha[i]*diag[GETI(i)] - 2);
        if(alpha[i] > 0)
            ++nSV;
    }
```

> Note that we group data in the same class together before calling this
> subroutine. Thus the order of your training instances has been
> changed. You can sort your data (e.g., positive instances before
> negative ones) before using liblinear. Then indices will be the same.